# T-SQL query to return the location of an application .exe

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell

What is the best way to find the path of an application, that could be installed anywhere on multiple types of PC/operating system.

I need to do this in SQL Server, the version could be 2008 all the way up to 2014.

I have the following that works well and returns what I need.

```
DECLARE @findpath varchar(500) = 'powershell.exe -noprofile (get-itemproperty -literalpath ''HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\App.exe'').''(default)'''
DECLARE @foundpath table(id int identity(1,1), [path] varchar(500)) 
    INSERT @foundpath 
       EXEC xp_cmdshell @findpath
```

My problem is the application doesn't always exist under that registry location so I need an alternative way of finding it.

Presuming the application is installed to the same directory as the SQL database files, I have tried using the WHERE command but I can't always guarantee the application is going to be installed to the same location, and sometimes it may be installed to a different drive letter.

```
IF (SELECT left([path],16) FROM @foundpath WHERE id = 1) = 'Get-ItemProperty'

    BEGIN 
       DECLARE @where varchar(500) = 'WHERE /R '+(
       SELECT distinct vs.volume_mount_point
       FROM sys.master_files AS f WITH (NOLOCK)
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.[file_id]) AS vs )+' '+'App.exe'
       INSERT @foundpath 
          EXEC xp_cmdshell @where
    END
```

Comment: This will find `odbcad32.exe` anywhere on C drive: `xp_cmdshell 'dir /s C:\odbcad32.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can list the apps shown in the GUI of "Add or remove programs" using the command line. Maybe you can use `wmic product get description` (I ran it in PowerShell), which I found by looking around online. It took a while to run and doesn't include all my apps.

Perhaps the app does something consistently that you can rely on. For example, it might set an env variable (e.g., PATH) regardless of where the installation directory is.